# Hi, I am new to vb.net, I am using Visual Studio 2010. I need one solution,my query is as below

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, treeview

I am creating one desktop application where I have 3 forms(Form1,Form2,Form3).

In Form1 I created 2 Panels (`Panel1` and `Panel2`).

In Panel1 there are 2 buttons which will help to slide Panel1 and in Panel1 I created one *TreeView*, so in runtime whenever I click the node on the left panel, either form2 or form3 will be loaded on right panel(Panel2).

Now the problem is sometimes the users may require to see both the forms opened simultaneously,so can anyone please suggest a code so that when I right click the node in a treeview in the left panel(Panel1) I get some dropdown such as "Open in a New Window"

Comment: you should [read this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then rewrite your question competely

Comment: Pluto What's wrong in my question, I explained it in detail so that people clearly understand abt my query

Comment: You obviously didn't read anything in the link. For starters, your title should be about your question. You should also include more specific information about your question. And finally, questions that include the phrase "please suggest a code" typically aren't received well.

Answer (score 0):

*"In Form1 I created 2 Panels (Panel1 and Panel2).

In Panel1 there are 2 buttons which will help to slide Panel1.

Panel1 I created one Tree View, so in runtime whenever I click the node on the <strike>left panel</strike> TreeView, either form2 or form3 will be loaded on right panel (Panel2)."*

Why do you use Panel2 ?

- Set your Form1 `IsMDIContainer` Property to False if already set to True
- Remove `Panel2`
- `Dock` your `Panel1` on the left if not already set (config its preffered size - already done that way I assume)
- Set your Form1 `IsMDIContainer` Property to True (again) so Panel1 is visible all the way, and you can put as many MDIChild on the remaining area on the right where Panel2 was.
- Then make `Form2` and `Form3` as `MDI children` of Form1 (there are tons of code out there explaining how to)
- Then create code to handle the way Form2 and Form3 will occupy the area at the same time or one at a time.

Of course, if your Form1 was already an MDI container OR you managed to make Panel2 act as an MDI container (which is possible) *you shouldn't have forgotten* to point that out, that's a reason why it is said that the question misses some details to clearly visualize the issue.

- do you have control on Form2 and Form3 size, location, docking style and border style ? If yes, give details...
- how is the layout altered when you maximize/unmaximize/resize Form1, Form2 and Form3 ?

...

Comment: First of all sorry for not being clear about my topic."Of course, if your Form1 was already an MDI container OR you managed to make Panel2 act as an MDI container (which is possible)", as i am new to vb.net as well as to the developing stream i dont know much about MDI Container, i dint do any changes in that. Just now i checked the IsMdiContainer property, its been set to false

Comment: And about size of the form, i set all the form size to (1280,780) in the design view. Here the users will be using Dell Desktops so the size which i have specified will fit in those systems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable code, it will be realy nice if you explain me more about my issue

Comment: Hey i found the solution, i used the below code to open the page in separateform :                                                        Sub treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles tre_Bpo.NodeMouseDoubleClick

        Dim fm2 As New Form2()
        Dim fm3 As New Form3()
        If e.Node.Text.Contains("Search") Then
            fm3.Show()
        Else : e.Node.Text.Contains("Candidate Information")
            fm2.Show()
        End If
    End Sub